# Oracle context index creation script

Tags: oracle, indexing, ddl, oracle-text

I need to generate the full Oracle CONTEXT index creation script for the index that already exists.

I'm pretty sure, that I've once found how to do it in Oracle documentation, but now, I can't. I need something like DBMS_METADATA.get_ddl, but more detailed.
What I mean is when I create an index like

```
CREATE INDEX myindex ON docs(text) INDEXTYPE IS CTXSYS.CONTEXT;
```

Oracle does many things by default, like configuring datastore,stoplist and so on.
I'd like to see all CTX_DDL procedures that are called implicitly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `ctx_report.describe_index` or `ctx_report.create_index_script`:

```
set long 500000
select ctx_report.describe_index('MYINDEX') from dual;
```

or

```
select ctx_report.create_index_script('MYINDEX') from dual;
```

Originally answered on [OracleAskTom](http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0%3a%3a%3a%3aP11_QUESTION_ID:37336026927381). Also another one [OracleFaqs](http://www.orafaq.com/forum/t/98727/2/).

[More info on creating index reports](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10500_01/text.920/a96518/crptpkg.htm)